# How can I setup my SQL Server LocalDB to be as close to a normal SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, localdb

SQL Server LocalDb does not support "sa" login out of the box.

It also does not like connections from other users nor it stays up enough.

So I need a way to enable most of the normal and expected functionality of a normal SQL Server on a LocalDB server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a shared instance of the Local db

```
SqlLocalDB.exe create "DeptLocalDB"
SqlLocalDB.exe share "DeptLocalDB" "DeptSharedLocalDB"
SqlLocalDB.exe start "DeptLocalDB"
SqlLocalDB.exe info "DeptLocalDB"
```

The last command will give you the pipename.
Create an sql alias to that pipe name, open C:\WINDOWS\system32\cliconfg.exe and create it in the alias tab.

If using x64 also add the alias at `Start` > `Sql Server Configuration Manager` > `Sql Native Client`. I had to install **Sql Server Shared Features** to get that option in `Start Menu`. 
https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/f/8/7f8a9c43-8c8a-4f7c-9f92-83c18d96b681/SQL2019-SSEI-Expr.exe
[image: sql server feature selection]

*BONUS:* If you name your alias `localhost` now you have almost the same as SQL Express.

Connect to that alias using windows authentication and

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'user instance timeout', 30;
GO
```

To configure the sa password do:

```
ALTER LOGIN sa ENABLE ;
GO
ALTER LOGIN sa WITH PASSWORD = '<enterStrongPasswordHere>' ;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a SQL Server instance that works just like a regular one, you can install SQL Server Express. LocalDB was specifically intended to be more lightweight and easier to administer than Express, but if you need a server that runs continuously, you're better off with Express.

Comment: I don't want to install anything and the good bits of LocalDB is that it shuts down itself saving resources when I'm not using it.

Comment: LocalDB didn't come from nothing... It came with your Visual Studio installation. Previously, Visual Studio installed SQL Server Express. The resource argument is a point, though -- but then the complaint that it doesn't stay "up enough" is curious. I guess SQL Server Express stays up *too much*. :-)

Comment: True, i've correct the value, it's 30 minutes normally what I set.